# imagecopy changes the color in the photo

Tags: php, gd

i use imagecreatefromjpeg for open a photo

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("primary_image.jpg");
```

and then create a empty photo

```
$main = imagecreate(imagesx($image),imagesy($image)+50);
imagecolorallocate($main,255, 52, 54);


imagecopy($main, $image, 0, $height, 0, 0, imagesx($main), imagesy($main));
```

but color of $image changed and Mixed with $main color

why?

thanks in advance

Comment: Did it change to red? "_and Mixed with $main color_" You don't have a `$main` color, `$main` is your image. From the [documentation on imagecolorallocate()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php): "_Note: The first call to imagecolorallocate() fills the background color in palette-based images - images created using imagecreate()._"

Comment: yes it changed to red . call imagecolorallocate  before  imagecreate ????? how ? @kerbholz

Comment: `255, 52, 54` is red. Do you need to set `imagecolorallocate` at all? Can't you just leave it out?

Comment: no i need use imagecolorallocate only for create red padding top of $image

Answer (score 2):

use imagecreatetruecolor instead of imagecreate

Comment: imagecreatetruecolor work fine but create a black empty photo . i need create blue or other color padding on primary image

Comment: @MJ7 well then fill your newly created image with a red “background” first - http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php

Comment: ops work like a charm. i create a imagecreatetruecolor and fill this red by imagefill . thanks bro .